# Superstruct custom validation dependent other field

Tags: typescript

I would like to perform the following validation by using Superstruct.

Field A and field B are both strings.
If both are strings with a length of 1 or more, or both are null or strings with a length of 0, the validation will pass.
Validation will fail if one is null and the other is a string with length 1 or more.

```
{
  fieldA: 'aaa',
  fieldB: 'bb' 
}
```

=> pass

```
{
  fieldA: '',
  fieldB: null 
}
```

=> pass

```
{
  fieldA: '',
  fieldB: 'bb' 
}
```

=> fail

```
{
  fieldA: null,
  fieldB: 'bb' 
}
```

=> fail

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPJMzN) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I wanna do runtime validation by superstruct, not type check

Comment: Oh okay, superstruct is some library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `define` function to define the custom `Null` validator and the `dynamic` function to decide the accepted value(s) of `fieldB` based on the `fieldA`.

```
import { isNull } from 'lodash';
import { assert, object, string, dynamic, empty, nullable, define } from 'superstruct';

const Null = define<any>('Null', (value) => isNull(value));

const validator = object({
  fieldA: nullable(string()),
  fieldB: dynamic((_value, parent) => {
    if (isNull(parent.branch[0].fieldA)) {
      return empty(string());
    } else if (parent.branch[0].fieldA === '') {
      return Null;
    }

    return nullable(string());
  }),
});
```